# positioning of an SVG based on the animation SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I'm trying to make a [submarine](https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/447/447773.svg) (SVG) seem as if it's floating on top of a 
wave (also SVG).

Since the wave is constantly going up and down, I want the submarine to be centered vertically (x), but be moving horizontally on top of the wave.

This is the code for the wave

```css
// best seen at 1500px or less

html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
  background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,254,234,1) 0%, rgba(255,254,234,1) 35%, #B7E8EB 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ocean { 
  height: 5%;
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  background: #015871;
}

.wave {
  background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85486/wave.svg) repeat-x; 
  position: absolute;
  top: -198px;
  width: 6400px;
  height: 198px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.wave:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: -175px;
  animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -.125s infinite, swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes wave {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: -1600px;
  }
}

@keyframes swell {
  0%, 100% {
    transform: translate3d(0,-25px,0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate3d(0,5px,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ocean">
  <div class="wave"></div>
  <div class="wave"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a class called 'sub' to get your picture formatted and also to add the animation. Notice I added the 'ease-out' as the animation timing function so that it goes down fast but up slower to keep up with the wave timing. But this is also just a result of tweaking the parameters and the animation 'updown' just right so that its working in the opposite direction to the wave based on how it starts. This is one way to do it, if you want to tweak the height or the ease out just change the seconds on ease-out in the 'sub' class or tweak the pixel count in the updown function. Hope this helps!

```css
// best seen at 1500px or less

   

 html, body { height: 100%; }
    body {
      background:radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,254,234,1) 0%, rgba(255,254,234,1) 35%, #B7E8EB 100%);
      overflow: hidden;
    }


    .sub{
       position: absolute;
       top: 85%;
       left: 50%;
       width: 100px;
       height: 100px;
       margin-top: -100px; /* Start height margin */
       margin-left: -50px; /* Half the width */
       animation: updown 7s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1) infinite;
       animation-timing-function:ease-in-out;
       transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
     }

    .ocean { 
      height: 5%;
      width:100%;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0;
      left:0;
      background: #015871;
    }

    .wave {
      background: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/85486/wave.svg) repeat-x; 
      position: absolute;
      top: -198px;
      width: 6400px;
      height: 198px;
      animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.48, 0.63, 0.53) infinite;
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    }

    .wave:nth-of-type(2) {
      top: -175px;
      animation: wave 7s cubic-bezier( 0.36, 0.45, 0.63, 0.53) -.125s infinite, 
      swell 7s ease -1.25s infinite;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    @keyframes wave {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -1600px;
      }
    }

    @keyframes swell {
      0%, 100% {
        transform: translate3d(0,-25px,0);
      }
      50% {
        transform: translate3d(0,5px,0);
      }
    }

        @keyframes updown {
      0%, 100% {
            transform: translate3d(0,-40px,0);
      }
      70% {
            transform: translate3d(0,45px,0);
      }
    }
```

```html
<img class = "sub" src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/447/447773.svg">
    <div class="ocean">
      <div class="wave"></div>
      <div class="wave"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I never thought of syncing the submarine's animation with the wave's animation.

Comment: If this answered your question, I'd appreciate if you marked it as accepted. Otherwise let me know how I can improve the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I saw that when it was the code snippet was in full screen, it was out of sync - is this because it uses px?

Comment: Yes you're right sorry about that I changed it to make the full page timed better. I also changed the curve on the .sub class. For reference, if you want a certain animation timing function, this site is useful: https://css-tricks.com/ease-out-in-ease-in-out/ I chose ease-in-out because the sub needs to be slow at the end points to match the movement of the wave. The easiest thing to tweak to get the timing right is the % parameter in the (@keyframes updown) part. I changed it from 50% to 70% so that its timed better with the wave. That had the most affect on the sync of the wave and boat.

Comment: After the changes you made, I believe you have solved my questions. Thanks for helping!